# Erro com namespace

Tags: php, construtor, namespace

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas: Dentro da pasta Form existe um arquivo chamado Form.php (entre outros). O Form.php pertence a namespace 'Livro\Widgets\Form'. Existe outra pasta com o nome Wrapper e dentro dela tem o arquivo FormWrapper.php que pertence a namespace 'Livro\Widgets\Wrapper'. No construtor da classe FormWrapper é pra receber um objeto da Classe Form. Ai que vem o problema, o php não reconhece o s namespaces informados pelos 'use' e quando eu rodo o projeto aparece a seguinte mensagem:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Livro\Widgets\Wrapper\FormWrapper::__construct() must be an instance of Livro\Widgets\Wrapper\Form, instance of Livro\Widgets\Form\Form given, called in C:\wamp64\www\projetos\phpoo4ed\App\Control\ContatoForm.php on line 20 and defined in C:\wamp64\www\projetos\phpoo4ed\Lib\Livro\Widgets\Wrapper\FormWrapper.php on line 14

Sendo que na pasta Wrapper não existe o arquivo Form. Alguma solução?

```
use Livro\Control\ActionInterface;
use Livro\Widgets\Form\FormElementInterface;

namespace Livro\Widgets\Form;

class Form {

    protected $title;
    protected $name;
    protected $fields;
    protected $actions;

    public function __construct($name = 'my_form') {
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function addField($label, FormElementInterface $object, $size = '100%') {
        $object->setSize($size);
        $object->setLabel($label);
        $object->fields[$object->getName()] = $object;
    }

    public function addAction($label, ActionInterface $action) {
        $this->actions[$label] = $action;
    }

    public function setData($object) {
        foreach ($this->fields as $name => $field) {
            if ($name and isset($object->$name)) {
                $field->setValue($object->$name);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getData($class = 'stdClass') {
        $object = new $class;

        foreach ($this->fields as $key => $fieldObject) {
            $val = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : '';
            $object->$key = $val;
        }

        foreach ($$_FILES as $key => $content) {
            $object->$key = $content['tmp_name'];
        }

        return $object;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getFields() {
        return $this->fields;
    }

    public function getActions() {
        return $this->actions;
    }
}


<?php
use Livro\Widgets\Base\Element;
use Livro\Widgets\Container\Panel;
use Livro\Widgets\Form\Button;
use Livro\Widgets\Form\Form;

namespace Livro\Widgets\Wrapper;

class FormWrapper {

    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(Form $form) {
        $this->decorated = $form;
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        return call_user_func(array($this->decorated, $method), $parameters);
    }

    public function show() {
        $element = new Element('form');
        $element->class = 'form-horizontal';
        $element->enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
        $element->method = 'post';
        $element->names = $this->decorated->getName();
        $element->width = '100%';

        foreach ($this->decorated->getFields() as $field) {
            $group = new Element('div');
            $group->class = 'form-group';

            $label = new Element('label');
            $label->class = 'col-sm-2 col-form-label';
            $label->add($field->getLabel());

            $col = new Element('div');
            $col->class = 'col-sm-10';
            $col->add($field);

            $field->class = 'form-control';
            $group->add($label);
            $group->add($col);
            $element->add($group);
        }

        $group = new Element('div');
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->decorated->getActions() as $label => $action) {
            $name = strtolower(str_replace('', '_', $label));
            $button = new Button($name);
            $button->setFormName($this->decorated->getName());
            $button->setAction($action, $label);
            $button->class = 'btn' . (($i == 0) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-secondary');
            $group->add($button);
            $i++;
        }

        $panel = new Panel($this->decorated->getTitle());
        $panel->addContentBody($element);
        $panel->addContentFooter($group);
        $panel->show();
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O erro está na declaração do 'namespace' ser depois das declarações de 'use. Basta inverter que dá certo.

```
namespace Livro\Widgets\Form;

use Livro\Control\ActionInterface;
use Livro\Widgets\Form\FormElementInterface;

class Form {
    ...
```